# Why is "@" symbol still causing errors?

Tags: php

I have an old site using Ubuntu and PHP 5.3. There is a cron script that hits an API to push/pull data. Recently I have been hit with an error when these scripts attempt to run: "Unidentified index: UserID" in the "appsettings.php" file.

```
$conn=db_connect();
if(!@$_SESSION["UserID"])
{
    $allowGuest=guestHasPermissions();
    $scriptname=getFileNameFromURL();
    if($allowGuest && $scriptname!="login.php" && $scriptname!="remind.php" && $scriptname!="register.php" && $scriptname!="registersuggest.php")
    {
        $_SESSION["UserID"]="Guest";
        $_SESSION["GroupID"]="<Guest>";
        $_SESSION["AccessLevel"]=ACCESS_LEVEL_GUEST;
        $auditObj = GetAuditObject();
        if($auditObj)
            $auditObj->LogLogin();
        if($globalEvents->exists("AfterSuccessfulLogin"))
        {           
            $dummy=array();
            $globalEvents->AfterSuccessfulLogin("","",$dummy);
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that using the "@" symbol isn't best practice, but I've been given explicit instruction to "just make it work". This has worked in the past, but since pushing up some styling changes I started getting this error.

Comment: maybe you need to check also if the array key exists http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php

Comment: You aren't using the `@` symbol on a function call, or something that returns a possible error.  Therefore, it is just trying to find an invalid array `@$_SESSION`.

Comment: Making it work doesn't mean using `@` . Using `@` does not make it work, it just doesn't tell you why it doesn't work.

Comment: i think by placing the ! before @ operator means @ will not Suppressed  "Unidentified index" message

Comment: are you using a custom error handler?

Answer (score 5):

To check to see if the `USERID` exists, try changing

```
if(!@$_SESSION["UserID"])
```

to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["UserID"])){...
...
} else { 
...// handle the error
}
```

Comment: It may be better to use `empty()` - also, you're condition is backwards, the error is captured in the if statement, not the else statement (unless you remove the `!`)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton, correct, it is backwards, but it should work to replace the SO's current line.  `empty()` could also work if that is what his logic flow requires.  I don't imagine there are too many UserID's set to `""` or `NULL`, though.

Comment: Hey, you never know! I do think at least mentioning in the answer that the condition may be backwards to get the expected results, the OP may not realize their logic is flawed.